# Regex for a comma delimited string containing certain letters only

Tags: javascript, regex

Working on creating a javascript regex that tests for this pattern: `a, b, c, etc`.. with certain letters.

In other words, letters separated by commas with a space after a comma. There needs to be at least one letter for the test to pass but can have an infinite amount after.

I have this so far:

```
/[cdefgab]+(, [cdefgab]+)*/
```

But am having trouble getting it to work as described.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a sequence of letters separated by a comma and a space you should use this regex:

```
/[cdefgab](, [cdefgab])*/
```

In your regex there's no need for the `+` quantifier if it's only one letter.

THIS is **[a DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW5gC5/1)**.

**EDIT:**

If it's meant to match exactly one letter **or** a sequence of letters separated with comma so you need to use the the {1} for exactly one occurence, your regex should be like this:

```
/[cdefgab]{1}(, [cdefgab])*/
```

**EDIT2:**

To match exactly the wanted sequence of characters and enable/disable the submit button accordingly you should use this regex `/^[cdefgab]{1}(, [cdefgab])*$/)` with the keyup event of the input, this a DEMO:

```js
var validateInput = function validateInput(input) {
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
  if (input.value.match(/^[cdefgab]{1}(, [cdefgab])*$/)) {

    console.log("matches");
    submitButton.disabled = false;

  } else {

    console.log("Unmatches");
    submitButton.disabled = "disabled";
  }
}
```

```html
Text:
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="validateInput(this);" />
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled/>
```

Comment: Ok, but what I need to do is not allow a form to be submitted unless it matches this exactly. It appears that once I start the sequence correctly, then place a number it still passes. Should that be happening?

Comment: @StackJuice No it shouldn't happen, please edit the question to include your whole code for the validation?

Comment: I think you almost have it. Let's say I start with a capital 'C' the button is disabled which is what I want, but as soon as I enter in a lowercase 'a' then it's disabled. I need this to be disabled unless it matches perfectly. Does that help?

Comment: @StackJuice2 take a look at my last EDIT, it will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[a-z](, [a-z])*/
```

This requires at least one letter, then can have any number of letters (0 or more) preceded by a comma and a space.

**edit:** if you're only looking for specific letters, replace instances of `[a-z]` with the letters you're looking for enclosed within square brackets. i.e. `[cefg]`

Comment: Great. I did what you suggested, but when I put a letter and then a period or dash it still passes. It needs to be comma only and have a space after it. What am I missing?

Comment: There's no need for pipes inside brackets !

Comment: updated, thanks @chsdk. @Stack Juice2, can you give an example string? If you want to exclude characters it becomes more difficult, since the beginning of the regex (`[a-z]`) will technically "pass" any string that contains a letter.